# Why is pytest client giving 404 error when I should be getting 400 error

Tags: pytest-django

**Problem summary:**
I am going through testdriven.io tdd django course and ran into an issue.  Pytest client has a different http response than what postman and httpie are giving for the same payload

**What I tried:**
I tried posting the same data on all three clients(httpie, postman, pytest) I am testing.  When i use httpie or postman i get a 400 error so I would expect when I write the test the testing client will see a 400 error but test fails because client is seeing 404.

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_add_movie_invalid_json_keys(client):
    movies = Movie.objects.all()
    assert len(movies) == 0

    resp = client.post(
      "api/movies/",
      {"title": "The Big Lebowski", "year": "1998"},
      content_type="application/json",
    )
    assert resp.status_code == 400

    movies = Movie.objects.all()
    assert len(movies) == 0
```

[pytest output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPe1K.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a forward slash in the URL. It should be `"/api/movies/"`.